# Alternating columns in Pandas to 0 or 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two alternating columns where one and only one of them is `NaN`, while the other is populated, and vice-verse. Example:

```
            A           B
2010-01-04  NaN         0.000000
2010-01-05  NaN         0.001561
2010-01-06  NaN         0.003196
2010-01-07  NaN         0.006061
2010-01-08  NaN         0.008041
2010-01-11  NaN         0.009228
2010-01-12  NaN         0.008100
2010-01-13  NaN         0.008549
2010-01-14  NaN         0.009624
2010-01-15  NaN         0.008482
2010-01-19  0.006729    NaN
2010-01-20  0.005514    NaN
2010-01-21  -0.000830   NaN
2010-01-22  -0.008367   NaN
2010-01-25  -0.014079   NaN
2010-01-26  -0.019819   NaN
2010-01-27  -0.022431   NaN
```

What would be the quickest way to convert the columns with `NaN` into `0`, and any nonzero into `1`? For example, on the previous data, it would look like:

```
            A  B
2010-01-04  0  1
2010-01-05  0  1
2010-01-06  0  1
2010-01-07  0  1
2010-01-08  0  1
2010-01-11  0  1
2010-01-12  0  1
2010-01-13  0  1
2010-01-14  0  1
2010-01-15  0  1
2010-01-19  1  0
2010-01-20  1  0
2010-01-21  1  0
2010-01-22  1  0
2010-01-25  1  0
2010-01-26  1  0
2010-01-27  1  0
```

Comment: Just `df.notna()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(df.notna().astype(int))
```

Prints:

```
            A  B
2010-01-04  0  1
2010-01-05  0  1
2010-01-06  0  1
2010-01-07  0  1
2010-01-08  0  1
2010-01-11  0  1
2010-01-12  0  1
2010-01-13  0  1
2010-01-14  0  1
2010-01-15  0  1
2010-01-19  1  0
2010-01-20  1  0
2010-01-21  1  0
2010-01-22  1  0
2010-01-25  1  0
2010-01-26  1  0
2010-01-27  1  0
```